# Linear Kernel vs RBF kernel

Tags: kernel, svm, libsvm

I was reading through the section when to use linear kernel over RBF kernel in the following link :
http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf p.12.  Can someone please tell me what does he mean by very large features.  What quantity is he referring to 100s...1000s...10000s? As I read through the whole guid and readme and he does not specifically say what he means by LARGE.

Answer (score 2):

I consider using a linear kernel when the number of features is greater than 5K. 5K+ is large.

However, this mainly depends on "number of instances" x "number of features" on your training data. The linear kernel usually gives comparable results when the number of train instances is greater than 10 times the number of features.

Comment: Daniel could you give a link to a publication mentioning the linear kernel's capability of returning comparable results? Thanks!